# When can you start using the Pirate in Catan Cities and Knights / Seafarers?

Tags: catan, catan-cities-and-knights, catan-seafarers

In C&K rules, the robber cannot be moved at all until the first Barbarian Attack. When playing C&K combined with Seafarers, does this also apply to the pirate?

It would make a lot of sense to me, but I can't find anywhere that specifically spells it out either way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the rules to Sefarers, page 6:

> If you roll a "7" during your turn, you may elect to move the pirate
>   INSTEAD of the robber.

From the Cities and Knights rules, page 5:

> The robber cannot be moved until after the barbarians reach the island
>   of Catan for the first time.

Since the robber can't be moved until the barbarians attack, neither can the pirate, as there is no robber movement to replace.

Answer (score 1):

A strict reading of both the Seafarers and Cities & Knights rules says that the rule for waiting until the first Barbarian Attack applies *only* to the robber, and not the pirate, although there is a small ambiguity in that when you roll a 7 you *may* move the pirate instead of the robber, but technically you *cannot* move the robber until the first attack. Additionally, there seems to be no statement about the interaction in the FAQ either under the individual expansions or the crossover between them.

Given the ambiguity, you would probably have to decide which way to play via house rule.